# Protecting receiver privacy in a PayPal adaptive chained payment

Tags: paypal

We run a service where, amongst other things, members can exchange "digital goods" and are setting up to allow PayPal adaptive payments to cover to 'purchase for real money' aspect.

PayPal requires that we set the chain like this:

buyerMember -> sellerMember -> usTheService

The problem I am experiencing (payments themselves work great!) is that the buyer and seller members can look at their PayPal logs and see the name, mailing address, and maybe even the phone number of each other (mainly the sellerMember, as 'merchant' sees pretty much everything about the buyerMember

Our members would prefer not to exchange their physical mailing address (or, probably, in some cases not even their PayPal email account address) with other members.

Is there some way that I, as the adaptive payments API use, can suppress this personal information from being available between the members?

Answer (score 0):

I see the same issue and the only solution I have come up with is not to chain payments.  Instead, after I receive payment confirmation with payment details (e.g. which product was purchased), I invoke massPay to the seller.  Since these are digital goods, I can make it real-time if I choose. But, as per policy I established with sellers, I delay payment (at least) 48 to 72 hours to be able to handle refund requests from the buyer.